# Trying to generate a graph of 'proportions within proportions' in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID#   group  category1 category2 category3 category4 category5
1      a      1          0        1         0          0
2      a      0          0        0         0          1
3      b      1          1        1         0          0
```

So it contains a unique observation, that falls into one of four groups, and there are dummy variables for each observation indicating whether or not that observation is also in each category (note that many observations fall into multiple categories, and every observation will be in at least one category). What I want is a bar graph of the proportion of the unique observations that fall into each category, and then within each bar, to have the proportion of those observations that fall into each group. I found this similar image on google, so it would be similar to this type of graph. So my "categories" would be the games on the x-axis. and my "group" would be class level:

here is a link: https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.graphpad.com/faq/1944/images/1944.png

[image]

only difference is that my percentages wouldn't be 100% for each category. Any help would be greatly appreciated with this.

Thank you.

Comment: In the data you gave us, categories 4 and 5 have only 0 values, so if I sum values for each group and category, then plot that, their bars have no height. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry--I should have been clearer and will fix that in my question. Every observation will fall into at least 1 category (there is an "other" category).